# Show data in datagrid after add new record

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I want to show data from my database in dataGridView after saved new record. After I clicked button, the data saved, but not show in datagridview. How can I show that data?

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        {

            if (textBox_tarikh.Text == "" || textBox_resit.Text == "" || textBox_bayaran.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill In The Blank");

            }
            else
            {

                    String bResult = textBox_ic.Text;
                    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acap\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"; // add your conncetion string here
                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT Pembayaran (Description, Date, No_Resit, Payment, Studentic) VALUES (@Description, @date, @resit, @payment, @val)", connection);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", bResult);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", label4.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox_tarikh.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resit", textBox_resit.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment", textBox_bayaran.Text);
                    SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    connection.Open();
                    dataadapter.Fill(ds, "pembayaran_table");
                    connection.Close();
                    dataGridView3.DataSource = ds;
                    dataGridView3.DataMember = "pembayaran_table";

                   cmd.Connection.Open();
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("Data saved Successfully");
                }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //throw new Exception("Error " + ex.Message);
                        MessageBox.Show("Receipt No. is already use");
                    }

            }
```

Comment: Where is the code for binding the grid? make it as a method and call them after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string bResult = textBox_ic.Text;
   if (textBox_tarikh.Text == "" || textBox_resit.Text == ""||textBox_bayaran.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill In The Blank");
        }
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\acap\Documents\Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
   SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   SqlCommand cmd ;
   try
    {
      if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) connection.Open();
      cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT Pembayaran (Description, Date, No_Resit, Payment, Studentic) VALUES (@Description, @date, @resit, @payment, @val)", connection);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", bResult);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", label4.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(textBox_tarikh.Text));
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@resit", textBox_resit.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payment", textBox_bayaran.Text);
      cmd.Executenonquery();

      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Pembayaran",connection);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      da.Fill(dt);
      dataGridView3.DataSource = dt;
    }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
   }
   finally
   {
      if(connection.State == ConnectionState.Open) connection.Close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't see any data binding code in your snippet such as `DataGridView.DataSource = " "`, `DataGridView.DataBind();`

What you can try to do it after inserting data, make use of `@@IDENTITY` to retrieve the id of what you have inserted. Then make use of the id retrieved to capture the new record.

[@@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql)

I have noticed in your code snippet, you used the same query.

```
SqlDataAdapter dataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
```

You should write another `SqlStatement` and call it from `SqlDataAdapter`

For example:

```
// Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.  
string queryString =   
  "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM dbo.Customers";  
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);  

DataSet customers = new DataSet();  
adapter.Fill(customers, "Customers");
```

[Populating a DataSet from a DataAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter)

Comment: before this, I use the code like above just I edited, but give error says "Child list for field pembayaran_table cannot be created."

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your DataGridView's Datasource after inserting record to DB.

Comment: @DucAnhNguyen Answer will work can you please try that